# Error thown if the same number of values are passed to the stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I have this stored procedure that runs a `MERGE` upsert. It uses a table-valued parameter to get the information. I'm then calling it from my ASP.NET 5 project which I using Dapper ORM to call the stored procedure.

It works all fine when the database stored procedure and the model pass have the same number of fields, but that means if I need to update one database and have updated the ASP.NET project the database calls would start throwing an error or if I had to downgrade the current version of the ASP.NET project but can't downgrade the database would cause any error also.

Does anyone know a solution that would be able to solve this?

Basically, I'm looking for a way that they don't rely so strongly on being a particular version for it to work.

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].ItemType AS TABLE
(
    [Id]                VARCHAR(36)    NOT NULL,
    [Name]              VARCHAR(100)   NULL,
    [FullName]          VARCHAR(100)   NULL,
    [Description]       VARCHAR(4095)  NULL,
    [QuantityOnHand]    DECIMAL(18, 5) NULL,
    [IsActive]          BIT            NULL,
    [TimeCreated]       DATETIME2      NULL,
    [TimeModified]      DATETIME2      NULL,
    [AverageCost]       DECIMAL(18, 5) NULL,
    [SellingPrice]      DECIMAL(18, 5) NULL,
    [ExtCaseText]       VARCHAR(255)   NULL,
    [ExtCaseValue]      INT            NULL ,
    [Barcode]           VARCHAR(50)    NULL,
    [Brand]             VARCHAR(450)   NULL,
    [PurchaseCost]      DECIMAL(18, 5) NULL,
    [OurBrand]          BIT            NULL,
    [Vendor]            VARCHAR(450)   NULL 
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].UpsertItem
    @UpdateRecords dbo.ItemType READONLY,
    @LastModifiedSync DATETIME2 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO 
        qbItems AS Target
    USING 
        @UpdateRecords AS Source ON Target.Id = Source.Id

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE  
            SET Target.Id = Source.Id,
                Target.[Name] = Source.[Name],
                Target.[FullName] = Source.[FullName],
                Target.[Description] = Source.[Description],
                Target.QuantityOnHand = Source.QuantityOnHand,
                Target.IsActive = Source.IsActive,
                Target.[TimeCreated] = Source.[TimeCreated],
                Target.TimeModified = Source.TimeModified,
                Target.AverageCost = Source.AverageCost,
                Target.SellingPrice = Source.SellingPrice,
                Target.ExtCaseText = Source.ExtCaseText,
                Target.ExtCaseValue = Source.ExtCaseValue,
                Target.Barcode = Source.Barcode,
                Target.Brand = Source.Brand,
                Target.OurBrand = Source.OurBrand,
                Target.Vendor = Source.Vendor,
                Target.PurchaseCost = Source.PurchaseCost
            
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN           
        INSERT (Id, [Name], [FullName], [Description],
                QuantityOnHand, IsActive, [TimeCreated], TimeModified,
                AverageCost, SellingPrice, ExtCaseText, ExtCaseValue,
                Barcode, Brand, OurBrand, Vendor, PurchaseCost)
        VALUES (Source.Id, Source.[Name], Source.[FullName], Source.[Description],
                Source.QuantityOnHand, Source.IsActive, Source.[TimeCreated], Source.TimeModified,       
                Source.AverageCost, Source.SellingPrice, Source.ExtCaseText, Source.ExtCaseValue,
                Source.Barcode, Source.Brand, Source.OurBrand, Source.Vendor, Source.PurchaseCost);

    SELECT @LastModifiedSync = [TimeModified] 
    FROM qbItems 
    ORDER BY TimeModified ASC;
END
```

C# code to call procedure:

```
public bool Create(ref List<qbItem> items)
{
    // LastMod = new DateTime();
    if (items.Count <= 0) 
        return true;

    try
    {
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("UpdateRecords", items.Where(x => x.FullName != null).OrderBy(x => x.TimeModified).ToDataTable().AsTableValuedParameter("ItemType"));
        p.Add("LastModifiedSync", dbType: DbType.DateTime, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        p.Add("affectedRows", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

        using var connection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection.DefaultConnection);

        var affectedRows = connection.Execute("[dbo].[UpsertItem]", p,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            //LastMod = items.OrderByDescending(t => t.TimeModified).Select(x => x.TimeModified).First();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError(e.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    object[] values = new object[props.Count];

    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }

        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Please comment for any further information that you may need to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having your C# query the db for the definition of ItemType and adjust the datatable based on it

```
select *
from information_schema.domains
where data_type = 'table type'
```

You can use it to tell you about the db side type; probably a list of column names and types will do

Then you can build your datatable as you currently do, then adjust it by working out what columns to add and which to remove

```
 var incs = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName);

 var indb = (query the info schema and make a list)
```

Then you can work out which columns to remove and which to add:

```
var toRemove = incs.Except(indb);
var toAdd = indb.Except(incs);
```

And adjust the datatable accordingly

```
foreach(.. in toRemove)
  dt.Columns.Remove(..)
```

Add is probably a bit more of a pain because of mapping the db types to c# types, but not impossible